# Bug on reputation total

Tags: bug, status-completed

I edited a post and got **+2** reputation for that(345+2), at the same time (I think exact same moment) the user removed his post.

I know that Reputation gained for an approved suggested edit is lost when the post is deleted. (couple of times I lost reputation in this case). But **not** happened today, still my total reputation showing **347** but reputation summary showing as on screenshot.

The individual reputation showing correct count (information) but the total reputation score is wrong.

[image]

Comment: It's probably caching (usually is).

Comment: @Clive - I just opened it on another browser (IE) (right now I'm on FF). the reputation still showing 347. So I don't think it's a cache problem, Am I right?

Comment: Not browser caching, app caching

Comment: @Clive - Oh, ok I guess, logout and login clears app cache?

Comment: It might well do - if you logout/login is it 'fixed'?

Comment: No.. still same reputation (347).

Comment: Hrm, your edit got approved after the post was deleted by the OP. I'm gonna have to check whether we need to do anything or if this is something that's going to resolve itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the edit was approved after the post was deleted, so it took a bit for the system to catch up. The system did notice that you were "owed" a 2-point rep reduction, but it simply hadn't taken effect yet.

I forced a rep recalc on your profile, so you should see the accurate rep display:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @Anna Lear - Great!!. Thanks, but the sum of individuals gives 375, I think, still there needs add -1 to my total ;)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Everyone starts with 1 reputation and can never go below 1, so your earned rep will always be 1 less than what you have.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Sorry, my comments was not clear enough, I said there needs to add (-1) to my total.But I believe, there still needs to do something. As you said, it should display 1 less than what I have, but it's showing 1 greater what I have. If you want I'll make it as another post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for aberrations in your reputation, you can go to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/reputation and see raw data. there used to be *Trigger Reputation Recalc* button there, but sadly I can't see it now. Probably removed when [this got implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319).